# tf_version_script giving syntaxerror

Tags: linux, tensorflow, ld

The version of linux I am using is ubuntu 14.04. I wanted to know my tensorflow version, so I ran a script given in the tensorflow directory `tf_version_script.lds` with the command `ld tf_version_script.lds` and it gave this error-

```
ld:/home/me/tensorflow/tensorflow/tf_version_script.lds:1: syntax error
```

I had the directory mounted. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tf_version_script.lds` is a linker [version script](https://www.gnu.org/software/gnulib/manual/html_node/LD-Version-Scripts.html) used to specify to the GNU linker what symbols to make global, and what symbols to keep local. It has nothing to do with TensorFlow version, although I agree that its name is somewhat misleading.

If you have installed TensorFlow via the pip package, you can run the following to know what version of TensorFlow is installed :

```
$ pip freeze | grep tensorflow
# prints tensorflow==0.9.0
```

Or, if you have installed TensorFlow from sources, you can also print out the version in Python as follows :

```
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.__version__)
# print '0.9.0'
```

Comment: That explains it! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

In >jupyter notebook

```
 import tensorflow as tf
 import keras      as ks
 print("TensorFlow version : ")
 print(tf.__version__)
 print("Keras version : ")
 print(ks.__version__)

 or

 print("TensorFlow version : " + tf.__version__)
 print("Keras version : " + ks.__version__)
```

Out >Output after run

```
 TensorFlow version : 
 1.14.0
 Keras version : 
 2.2.4

 or

 TensorFlow version : 1.14.0
 Keras version : 2.2.4
```